# Concatenate list of lists

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to solve a problem (for practice) in which I have to write a function that concatenates all the elements in a given list of lists. In other words, if the input to this function is `[[1,2], [3,4]]`, then the output should be `[1,2,3,4]` (order is not important).

I was able to achieve it by using the code below, but I'm wondering if it's inefficient or can be made more elegant.

```
%% To achieve this, we use a helper function and an accumulator %%
% Append elements of Src list into Dest list
append_list([], Dest) -> Dest;
append_list([H|T], Dest) -> append_list(T, [H|Dest]).

concatenate_acc([H|T], FinalList) -> 
    FinalList1 = append_list(H, FinalList),
    concatenate_acc(T, FinalList1);
concatenate_acc([], FinalList) -> FinalList.

concatenate(L) -> concatenate_acc(L, []).
```

Sample output:

```
exercises2:concatenate([[1,2], [3,4]]).
[2,1,3,4]
```

Please comment on this!

Comment: Are you doing this to learn or just want to use this function somewhere? If just use, there's `lists:concat/1`.

Comment: @Dogbert It's for learning. Let me add that to the text as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L118) of [`lists:append/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#append-1) gives exactly what you need but in a simpler way I guess.

```
append([E]) -> E;
append([H|T]) -> H ++ append(T);
append([]) -> [].
```

It is always a good practice to take a look at the source code if there is already an implemented function in Erlang modules.

You may make a small modification to make it a tail recursion. Note that the accumulator `Acc` is on the right hand side of the `++` operator.

```
append2(List) -> append2(List,[]).
append2([], Acc) -> Acc;
append2([H|T],Acc) -> append2(T, H ++ Acc).
```

Comment: Thanks! But isn't the `++` way of joining lists inefficient? Joe's book specifically recommends against it.

Comment: AFAIK it is similar. Take a look also at [this List Handling chapter](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html#id68235). The only thing you need to consider when using `++` is that it is always better to append to the beginning of your `Acc`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! When you say append to the beginning of the accumulator, do you mean the `++` should be the first statement, or something else?

Comment: Prefer `H ++ Acc` instead of `Acc ++ H` .